# I just need tensorflow function equivalent to cv2.threshold nad np.std to use in tensorflow 1.8

Tags: tensorflow

```
 I need to convert the following line into its tensorflow equivalent in tf version 1.8
 but I am not getting the appropriate functions equivalent to cv2.threshold and np.std in TF  1.8

 ret,mask = cv2.threshold(mask,tf.reduce_mean(mask)+1.2*np.std(mask),255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

The output of the line should be a binary mask

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like this:

```py
thr = tf.math.reduce_mean(mask) + 1.2 * tf.math.reduce_std(mask)
mask = tf.cast(mask > thr, tf.uint8) * 255
```